# Перенос слова "взгляд"

Tags: орфография, перенос

Слово "взгляд" как-то можно перенести? Как оно делится на слоги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. В слове один гласный звук, соответственно один слог и перенос невозможен.

Более того, в этом слове нет даже неслоговых гласных призвуков, котрые иногда выделяют в таких словах как рубль, театр ([руб(ы)ль][тят(ы)р]). Поэтому вопрос несколько озадачивает. вы действительно спрашивали о переносе и числе слогов?

Comment: Просьба от администрации форума не комментировать вопросы или делать это в комментариях, а не в ответах. То, что очевидно для Вас, для спрашивающего, видимо, вызывает сложность. Задача нашего форума - отвечать на вопросы пользователей, а не комментировать их компетентность.  
Спасибо

Comment: ОК, я поменял формулировку, на будущее тоже учту. Но я не имел в виду "компетентность вопроса" (а что это вообще такое?) "Вопрос удивляет" означало, что мне не ясна логика, по которой автор мог предположить иное, т.е. возможность переноса и более одного слога.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же нельзя переносить слово, в неё лишь одна гласная буква, вот верный признак того, что нельзя переносить такие слова!